# Governor Limits Across Object Triggers

Tags: trigger, governorlimits

I am architecting a solution and wanted to know whether information exists regarding the depth of governor limits, when a trigger invokes another trigger (different objects).

For example, I have 2 Objects, A + B.

1. When a user updates **Object A** 10 SOQL queries are run
2. Before the transaction is complete, a record is updated in **Object B** by Trigger on **Object A** (this trigger relies on 5 SOQL queries)
3. Information is then queried from **Object B** and, finally, the **Object A** trigger is complete.

So, do I have 2 separate sets of governor limits?  What's my cumulative SOQL Queries used?    Are there other ramifications I should be aware of when relying on cross-object triggers?

Comment: Governor limits are for the entire transaction (Synchronous). From start to end across all classes, other triggers, field updates, and triggers and classes again until the transaction ends the counts pile up.

Comment: ok, posting as an answer then since it seems to meet your needs and answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Governor limits are for the entire transaction (Synchronous). From start to end across all classes, other triggers, field updates, and triggers and classes again until the transaction ends the counts pile up